# Restoring Vim macro with control character

Tags: vim

I'm using GVim on Linux, and am trying to restore a macro by sourcing a vim script, using `:source` command. I notice that if the saved macro contains a return key, a `^J` is implicitly appended, thereby altering macro behaviour. It happens even if I enter them manually at command line. For example:

```
let @c = "<CR>"
```

If I display the register contents, it shows the `^J` crept in:

```
:reg c
--- Registers ---
"c    ^M^J
```

If I were to record with only a return key, there's no spurious additions. Any clues why the `^J` is creeping in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The registers have a heuristic that determine their characterwise / linewise mode. A string ending with Enter triggers the linewise detection, and that causes Vim to append the `^J`. You can use `setreg()`, which allows you to specify the register mode via the optional third argument:

```
:call setreg('c', "\<CR>", 'c')
:reg c
--- Registers ---
"c   ^M
```